# Setting binding in WCF service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

This may seem like a really easy question but I can't seem to figure it out at all.

I'm trying to create a new WCF service, and I'm new to having to secure them.  I'm using a custom username/password for authentication.  The problem [right now anyways] that I seem to be running into is that I can't figure out how to define the service to use the WSHttpBinding (on the service side, not the client side).

Am I missing something incredibly simple?  Any pointers and/or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here's my code so far:
**IAccountService**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAccountService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool IsCardValid(string cardNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    bool IsAccountActive(string cardNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    int GetPointBalance(string cardNumber);
}
```

**Service web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

      <StructureMapServiceBehavior />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="StructureMapServiceBehavior" type="Marcus.Loyalty.WebServices.Setup.StructureMapServiceBehavior, Marcus.Loyalty.WebServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="Marcus.Loyalty.WebServices.Account.IAccountService">
    <endpoint address=""
      binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Config"
      contract="Marcus.Loyalty.WebServices.Account.IAccountService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Config"/>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Testing app (console app)**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter card number");
        var number = Console.ReadLine();

        var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:59492/Account/AccountService.svc");
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

        var cf = new ChannelFactory<IAccountService>(binding, endPoint);
        cf.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser";
        cf.Credentials.UserName.Password = "Password1!";

        var service = cf.CreateChannel();
        var balance = service.IsAccountActive(number);

        Console.WriteLine("\nBALANCE: {0:#,#}", balance);

        Console.Write("\n\nPress Enter to continue");

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Testing app app.config**

```
<configuration>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:59492/Account/AccountService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IAccountService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Configure+WCF+WsHttpbinding&oq=Configure+WCF+WsHttpbinding&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.1.2045.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.R_LV8du4ijc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=453c61f1d2964b16&bpcl=39314241&biw=1097&bih=541

Comment: Do you have a config file? Many things in WCF can be defined in config

Comment: @marc_s - I do not, I was hoping to define that part in code, but if you could provide a sample, I'll do whatever works :)

Comment: I think you are missing a base address

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the abc (address, binding, contract) configuration into de web.config file (you can also do it programmatically. the b part, the binding, you can specify the `wsHttpBinding`

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name = "MyNamespace.MyService">
            <endpoint
            address = "http://localhost:8000/MyService"
            binding = "wsHttpBinding"
            contract = "MyNamespace.IMyContract" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you wish to enable security in a proper way, there is a lot of literature and options. You can use certificates, windows based, tokens, ... passing a username & password like a parameter could not be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extensive sample on MSDN ([How to: Specify a Service Binding in code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731833.aspx)) - but basically, you need to have:

- your service contract (`IMyService`)
- an implementation of that service (`MyService`)
- a code where you create your `ServiceHost` to host your service

You got all of that? Great!

In that case, just do something like this:

```
// Specify a base address for the service
string baseAddress = "http://YourServer/MyService";

// Create the binding to be used by the service.
WsHttpBinding binding1 = new WsHttpBinding();

using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding1, baseAddress);

    host.Open();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and now you should have your service host up and running, on your chosen base address and with the `wsHttpBinding` defined in code.

Comment: The only thing I'm unsure of (fairly new to WCF) is the `ServiceHost` you're talking about.  Is this referring to the app hosting the service?

Also, the error I'm getting right now is: `Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service`

Thanks!

Comment: @mmillican: yes, the `ServiceHost` is the class that you need in your application that will "host" the service. If you're using IIS to host your WCF service - in that case, you'd have to create a descendant of `ServiceHostFactory` to be able to provide your own custom version of a `ServiceHost` to IIS hosting your service. Sounds complicated - it's really not - see [Extending Hosting Using ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx) for a write up on how to do it